# Single spacing in todonotes with Elsarticle Class

Tags: spacing, elsarticle, todonotes

I would like to know how I can use single spacing (\singlespacing) in todonotes, considering Elsarticle Class, because I always get an error message about paragraph?

Following a minimal example:

```
%!Tex: LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[review,authoryear,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum,setspace}
\usepackage[textwidth=1.7cm]{todonotes}

\journal{TUG}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Doubt about LaTeX\tnoteref{Nota1}}
\tnotetext[Nota1]{This document was a collaborative effort.}

\author[Add1]{John Smith}
\ead{email@email.com}
\address[Add1]{TUG University}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
First word\sep Second word.
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at sapien vitae sapien ultricies sodales\todo{\tiny {\singlespacing Vivamus orci dui, posuere et suscipit placerat.}}.

Curabitur quam elit, tempus ut fringilla et, luctus sit amet nisl. Suspendisse mi odio, elementum quis blandit non, efficitur nec orci. Vivamus ullamcorper id justo quis posuere\todo{\tiny {\begin{spacing}{0.5} Vivamus orci dui, posuere et suscipit placerat.\end{spacing}}}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `setspace`: just use `\linespread{1}`, but remember to add `\par` at the end, or the paragraph would be set with the normal baselineskip.

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[textwidth=1.7cm]{todonotes}

\journal{TUG}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Doubt about LaTeX\tnoteref{Nota1}}
\tnotetext[Nota1]{This document was a collaborative effort.}

\author[Add1]{John Smith}
\ead{email@email.com}
\address[Add1]{TUG University}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
First word\sep Second word.
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Phasellus at sapien vitae sapien ultricies 
sodales\todo{\linespread{1}\tiny Vivamus orci dui, posuere et suscipit placerat.\par}.

Curabitur quam elit, tempus ut fringilla et, luctus sit 
amet nisl. Suspendisse mi odio, elementum quis blandit 
non, efficitur nec orci. Vivamus ullamcorper id justo quis 
posuere\todo{\linespread{1}\tiny Vivamus orci dui, posuere et suscipit placerat.\par}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to add a macro, say

```
\newcommand{\elstodo}[1]{%
  \todo{\linespread{1}\tiny #1\par}%
}
```

so as to be able to write simply

```
\elstodo{Vivamus ... placerat}
```

---

A less hackish solution:

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
  textwidth=1.7cm,
  textsize=singlespacetiny,
]{todonotes}

\newcommand{\singlespacetiny}{\linespread{1}\tiny}

\journal{TUG}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Doubt about LaTeX\tnoteref{Nota1}}
\tnotetext[Nota1]{This document was a collaborative effort.}

\author[Add1]{John Smith}
\ead{email@email.com}
\address[Add1]{TUG University}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
First word\sep Second word.
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\listoftodos

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Phasellus at sapien vitae sapien ultricies 
sodales\todo{Vivamus orci dui, posuere et suscipit placerat.}.

Curabitur quam elit, tempus ut fringilla et, luctus sit 
amet nisl. Suspendisse mi odio, elementum quis blandit 
non, efficitur nec orci. Vivamus ullamcorper id justo quis 
posuere\todo{Vivamus orci dui, posuere et suscipit placerat.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is main difference between \linespread{1} and setspacing?

Comment: @VAS That you don't need a package for it

Comment: this solution is working, but it crashes with command “\listoftodos”. Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: @VAS Yes, I have. ;-)

Comment: thanks. The problem was “\par” at end “\todo” command. I would hope that one day I will be able to help other people as you.